# Convert a list saved in a CSV-file back into a list again

Tags: python, csv

hopefully someone can help me.
I've already searched for several hours for a solution but still I didn't find one.

So, here is my problem:

I have written a script which scrapes some information from the web.

Which output are multiple lists like this one:

```
|['Pierre-Emerick Aubameyang', ['172', '114', '19', '9/13', '14', '0', '0', '19', '35', '13702', '22'], [['Borussia Dortmund', '17/18', '8', '10', '1', '2/3', '0', '0', '0', '-', '1', '714', '2'], ['Borussia Dortmund', '16/17', '32', '31', '2', '2/4', '3', '0', '0', '1', '5', '2780', '4'], ['Borussia Dortmund', '15/16', '31', '25', '5', '3/4', '4', '0', '0', '3', '9', '2468', '8'], ['Borussia Dortmund', '14/15', '33', '16', '7', '1/1', '4', '0', '0', '2', '9', '2715', '5'], ['Borussia Dortmund', '13/14', '32', '13', '4', '-/-', '1', '0', '0', '12', '11', '1889', '3'], ['AS St.-Etienne', '12/13', '36', '19', '0', '1/1', '2', '0', '0', '1', '-', '3136', '0']]]|
```

and saved this list with the following (maybe it helps, finding a solution):

```
with open('filename.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=",", quotechar='|')
    for pieler in spielers:
        writer.writerow([pieler])
```

At the moment I only get line per line as a string, but I don't understand/find a solution to convert it then into a list like the list mentioned below.

The result at the end should be:

```
[['Pierre-Emerick Aubameyang', ['172', '114', '19', '9/13', '14', '0', '0', '19', '35', '13702', '22'], [['Borussia Dortmund', '17/18', '8', '10', '1', '2/3', '0', '0', '0', '-', '1', '714', '2'], ['Borussia Dortmund', '16/17', '32', '31', '2', '2/4', '3', '0', '0', '1', '5', '2780', '4'], ['Borussia Dortmund', '15/16', '31', '25', '5', '3/4', '4', '0', '0', '3', '9', '2468', '8'], ['Borussia Dortmund', '14/15', '33', '16', '7', '1/1', '4', '0', '0', '2', '9', '2715', '5'], ['Borussia Dortmund', '13/14', '32', '13', '4', '-/-', '1', '0', '0', '12', '11', '1889', '3'], ['AS St.-Etienne', '12/13', '36', '19', '0', '1/1', '2', '0', '0', '1', '-', '3136', '0']]], ['Robert Lewandowski', ['235', '160', '38', '16/17', '21', '0', '1', '30', '47', '18456', '27'], [['FC Bayern München', '17/18', '8', '9', '0', '3/3', '0', '0', '0', '-', '1', '694', '1'], ['FC Bayern München', '16/17', '33', '30', '6', '5/5', '5', '0', '0', '2', '3', '2776', '9'], ['FC Bayern München', '15/16', '32', '30', '3', '2/2', '2', '0', '0', '3', '3', '2654', '5'], ['FC Bayern München', '14/15', '31', '17', '6', '1/1', '0', '0', '0', '3', '11', '2482', '5'], ['Borussia Dortmund', '13/14', '33', '20', '7', '4/4', '4', '0', '0', '2', '6', '2801', '4'], ['Borussia Dortmund', '12/13', '31', '24', '5', '1/2', '2', '0', '1', '2', '1', '2595', '2'], ['Borussia Dortmund', '11/12', '34', '22', '9', '-/-', '4', '0', '0', '-', '13', '2865', '1'], ['Borussia Dortmund', '10/11', '33', '8', '2', '-/-', '4', '0', '0', '18', '9', '1589', '0']]], [..., [...], [[...], [...], [...]]]]
```

So a list, in which many more lists are (one list per player).

The list I'm saving into the file I want to open correctly looks similar to this (jsut with many more players in it):

> [['Pierre-Emerick Aubameyang', ['172', '114', '19', '9/13', '14', '0',
>   '0', '19', '35', '13702', '22'], [['Borussia Dortmund', '17/18', '8',
>   '10', '1', '2/3', '0', '0', '0', '-', '1', '714', '2'], ['Borussia
>   Dortmund', '16/17', '32', '31', '2', '2/4', '3', '0', '0', '1', '5',
>   '2780', '4'], ['Borussia Dortmund', '15/16', '31', '25', '5', '3/4',
>   '4', '0', '0', '3', '9', '2468', '8'], ['Borussia Dortmund', '14/15',
>   '33', '16', '7', '1/1', '4', '0', '0', '2', '9', '2715', '5'],
>   ['Borussia Dortmund', '13/14', '32', '13', '4', '-/-', '1', '0', '0',
>   '12', '11', '1889', '3'], ['AS St.-Etienne', '12/13', '36', '19', '0',
>   '1/1', '2', '0', '0', '1', '-', '3136', '0']]], ['Robert Lewandowski',
>   ['235', '160', '38', '16/17', '21', '0', '1', '30', '47', '18456',
>   '27'], [['FC Bayern München', '17/18', '8', '9', '0', '3/3', '0', '0',
>   '0', '-', '1', '694', '1'], ['FC Bayern München', '16/17', '33', '30',
>   '6', '5/5', '5', '0', '0', '2', '3', '2776', '9'], ['FC Bayern
>   München', '15/16', '32', '30', '3', '2/2', '2', '0', '0', '3', '3',
>   '2654', '5'], ['FC Bayern München', '14/15', '31', '17', '6', '1/1',
>   '0', '0', '0', '3', '11', '2482', '5'], ['Borussia Dortmund', '13/14',
>   '33', '20', '7', '4/4', '4', '0', '0', '2', '6', '2801', '4'],
>   ['Borussia Dortmund', '12/13', '31', '24', '5', '1/2', '2', '0', '1',
>   '2', '1', '2595', '2'], ['Borussia Dortmund', '11/12', '34', '22',
>   '9', '-/-', '4', '0', '0', '-', '13', '2865', '1'], ['Borussia
>   Dortmund', '10/11', '33', '8', '2', '-/-', '4', '0', '0', '18', '9',
>   '1589', '0']]], ['Martin Harnik', ['312', '102', '6', '3/5', '35',
>   '3', '1', '56', '84', '23110', '17'], [['Hannover 96', '17/18', '8',
>   '5', '0', '-/-', '1', '0', '0', '-', '4', '692', '1'], ['Hannover 96',
>   '16/17', '30', '17', '2', '3/4', '4', '0', '0', '5', '12', '2320',
>   '7'], ['VfB Stuttgart', '15/16', '19', '2', '0', '-/-', '2', '0', '0',
>   '8', '5', '1000', '0'], ['VfB Stuttgart', '14/15', '28', '9', '3',
>   '-/-', '1', '1', '1', '2', '11', '2236', '3'], ['VfB Stuttgart',
>   '13/14', '30', '10', '0', '0/1', '6', '0', '0', '7', '9', '2031',
>   '4'], ['VfB Stuttgart', '12/13', '30', '6', '0', '-/-', '6', '2', '0',
>   '1', '-', '2500', '1'], ['VfB Stuttgart', '11/12', '34', '17', '1',
>   '-/-', '4', '0', '0', '1', '12', '2768', '1'], ['VfB Stuttgart',
>   '10/11', '32', '8', '0', '-/-', '7', '0', '0', '15', '5', '1877',
>   '0'], ['Fortuna Düsseldorf', '09/10', '30', '13', '0', '-/-', '3',
>   '0', '0', '1', '9', '2571', '0'], ['SV Werder Bremen', '08/09', '8',
>   '0', '0', '-/-', '0', '0', '0', '6', '-', '318', '0'], ['SV Werder
>   Bremen II', '08/09', '8', '1', '0', '-/-', '1', '0', '0', '-', '3',
>   '704', '0'], ['SV Werder Bremen', '07/08', '9', '1', '0', '-/-', '0',
>   '0', '0', '6', '2', '298', '0'], ['SV Werder Bremen II', '07/08',
>   '12', '3', '0', '-/-', '0', '0', '0', '-', '3', '1038', '0'], ['SV
>   Werder Bremen II', '06/07', '21', '8', '0', '-/-', '0', '0', '0', '4',
>   '6', '1596', '0'], ['SV Werder Bremen II', '05/06', '13', '2', '0',
>   '-/-', '0', '0', '0', '-', '3', '1161', '0']]], ['Mark Uth', ['152',
>   '76', '12', '5/5', '15', '0', '0', '34', '55', '10458', '5'], [['TSG
>   1899 Hoffenheim', '17/18', '7', '5', '0', '-/-', '0', '0', '0', '1',
>   '2', '533', '1'], ['TSG 1899 Hoffenheim', '16/17', '22', '7', '3',
>   '-/-', '4', '0', '0', '10', '8', '1155', '1'], ['TSG 1899 Hoffenheim
>   II', '16/17', '1', '1', '0', '-/-', '0', '0', '0', '-', '1', '58',
>   '1'], ['TSG 1899 Hoffenheim', '15/16', '25', '8', '1', '-/-', '2',
>   '0', '0', '9', '8', '1405', '2'], ['SC Heerenveen', '14/15', '32',
>   '15', '8', '3/3', '6', '0', '0', '-', '15', '2664', '0'], ['1. FC
>   Köln', '11/12', '-', '0', '0', '-/-', '0', '0', '0', '-', '-', '-',
>   '0'], ['1. FC Köln II', '11/12', '15', '9', '0', '-/-', '3', '0', '0',
>   '2', '2', '1179', '0'], ['1. FC Köln', '10/11', '-', '0', '0', '-/-',
>   '0', '0', '0', '-', '-', '-', '0'], ['1. FC Köln II', '10/11', '23',
>   '7', '0', '1/1', '0', '0', '0', '8', '5', '1473', '0'], ['1. FC Köln',
>   '09/10', '24', '24', '0', '1/1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '14', '1938',
>   '0'], ['1. FC Köln II', '09/10', '3', '0', '0', '-/-', '0', '0', '0',
>   '3', '-', '53', '0'], ['SCB Viktoria Köln 1994', '06/07', '-', '0',
>   '0', '-/-', '0', '0', '0', '-', '-', '-', '0']]]]

Thanks for helping, guys!

greetings from germany

### **#####EDIT#####**

I've found a solution for my problem:

```
with open('filename.csv', 'r', newline='') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=",", quotechar='|')
    for row in reader:
        for i in row:
            part1 = i.replace("[","").split(",", 1)
            name = part1[0].replace("'","")
            part2 = part1[1].split("],", 1)
            part3 = part2[1].split("],")
            player_games = []
            for ii in part3:
                player_games.append(ii.replace("]", "").replace("'", "").split(","))
            total_player = [name, zweite[0].replace("'", "").split(",")]
            total_player.append(player_games)
            liste.append(total_player)
```

This works fine, but I think there is a better one....

Comment: Please show us how the output would be for the CSV row containing the example you posted.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? What I want to do with these information at the end or how a "print" command would show a line?

Comment: How will the filename.csv first row look like when you wrote the row you just posted? The desired output not the actual output.

Comment: EDITED my question. Is that the info you wanted?

Comment: Oh, you are saving it into a CSV file and then want to restore it. Gotcha. Tell us how `spielers` look like before storing it in the CSV.

Comment: edited my request again

Comment: Have you considered other formats, like JSON, XML or YAML? CSV is intended for saving tabular data, not structured.

Comment: I agree with @igrinis, CSV doesn't fit that data, I would use JSON.That way loading and unloading the data from and to the file would be trivial as JSON stores `list`s as JSON arrays (same notation with square brackets)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `list[ list[ str, list[str], list[ list[str] ] ] ]` is a quite poor data storing format semantically. You may know what each part of the data is today but you should probably transform the inner lists into some more semantic container such as `collections.namedtuple`s or even `dict`s. Also, the second element for each player is just a straight addition of the third element's elements, so storing it in a file could be avoided to save disk space. I would suggest using `list[ collections.OrderedDict{ str: collections.OrderedDict{ str: collections.namedtuple(str, int, ...) } } ]`

```
from collections import namedtuple, OrderedDict

Stats = namedtuple('Stats', ['team', 's1', 's2', 's3', 's4', 's5', 's6', 's7', 's8', 's9', 's10', 's11', 's12'])
```

's1'-'s12' are integers representing the last 11 numbers of each season list as one of them is currently being represented as '-/-' and I'm splitting it into 2. I don't know which stat they represent, you should use more meaningful names such as 'goals', 'games', etc. As an example, Pierre-Emerick Aubameyang's season 17/18 will be `Stats(team='Borussia Dortmund', s1=8, s2=10, s3=1, s4=2, s5=3, s6=0, s7=0, s8=0, s9=None, s10=1, s11=714, s12=2)`
The season (ie '17/18') is not being stored inside this tuple as it will be the key of the dictionary holding this tuples.

To parse strings into integers considering the special case of '-' we will need a function:

```
def parseToInt(value):
    ''' Returns the value parsed to int or None if it can't be parsed '''
    try:
        return int(value)
    except ValueError:
        return None
```

If you don't like using `None` instead of '-' you can swap the last line to `return value` but I find more Pythonic to use `None`. You would also need to modify the `filter` first parameters later on.

Once we have all this set up, and with a data sample such as:

```
spielers = [
            [
             'Pierre-Emerick Aubameyang',
             ['172', '114', '19', '9/13', '14', '0', '0', '19', '35', '13702', '22'],
             [
              ['Borussia Dortmund', '17/18', '8', '10', '1', '2/3', '0', '0', '0', '-', '1', '714', '2'],
              ['Borussia Dortmund', '16/17', '32', '31', '2', '2/4', '3', '0', '0', '1', '5', '2780', '4'],
              ['Borussia Dortmund', '15/16', '31', '25', '5', '3/4', '4', '0', '0', '3', '9', '2468', '8'],
              ['Borussia Dortmund', '14/15', '33', '16', '7', '1/1', '4', '0', '0', '2', '9', '2715', '5'],
              ['Borussia Dortmund', '13/14', '32', '13', '4', '-/-', '1', '0', '0', '12', '11', '1889', '3'],
              ['AS St.-Etienne', '12/13', '36', '19', '0', '1/1', '2', '0', '0', '1', '-', '3136', '0']
             ]
            ],
            [
             'Robert Lewandowski',
             ['235', '160', '38', '16/17', '21', '0', '1', '30', '47', '18456', '27'],
             [
              ['FC Bayern München', '17/18', '8', '9', '0', '3/3', '0', '0', '0', '-', '1', '694', '1'],
              ['FC Bayern München', '16/17', '33', '30', '6', '5/5', '5', '0', '0', '2', '3', '2776', '9'],
              ['FC Bayern München', '15/16', '32', '30', '3', '2/2', '2', '0', '0', '3', '3', '2654', '5'],
              ['FC Bayern München', '14/15', '31', '17', '6', '1/1', '0', '0', '0', '3', '11', '2482', '5'],
              ['Borussia Dortmund', '13/14', '33', '20', '7', '4/4', '4', '0', '0', '2', '6', '2801', '4'],
              ['Borussia Dortmund', '12/13', '31', '24', '5', '1/2', '2', '0', '1', '2', '1', '2595', '2'],
              ['Borussia Dortmund', '11/12', '34', '22', '9', '-/-', '4', '0', '0', '-', '13', '2865', '1'],
              ['Borussia Dortmund', '10/11', '33', '8', '2', '-/-', '4', '0', '0', '18', '9', '1589', '0']
             ]
            ]
           ]
```

We could parse the raw data and store it in a file easily like this:

```
players = OrderedDict()
for spieler in spielers: # spieler = ['Pierre-Emerick Aubameyang', [...], [...]]
    stats = OrderedDict()
    for season in spieler[2]: # season = ['Borussia Dortmund', ...]
        while season[1] in stats:
            season[1] += "*"
        stats[season[1]] = Stats(season[0], *list(map(parseToInt, season[2:5] + season[5].split('/') + season[6:])))
    players[spieler[0]] = stats

with open('players.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(players, f)
```

To reload the data we could do the following:

```
from collections import namedtuple, OrderedDict

Stats = namedtuple('Stats', ['team', 's1', 's2', 's3', 's4', 's5', 's6', 's7', 's8', 's9', 's10', 's11', 's12'])

with open('players.json', 'r') as f:
    players = json.load(f, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)

for name, all_stats in loaded_players.items():
    for season, stats in all_stats.items():
        all_stats[season] = Stats(*stats)
```

Take a look at the code and comment if you do not understand any part so that I can further explain it.

**EDIT**

To operate with the data you could do things like:

1) Computing the career-long stats and showing them in a table:

```
print(" {:^25} | {:^3} | {:^3} | {:^2} | {:^5} | {:^2} | {:^2} | {:^2} | {:^2} | {:^3} | {:^5} | {:^3} ".format('Name', 's1', 's2', 's3', 's4/s5', 's6', 's7', 's8', 's9', 's10', 's11', 's12'))
print("-"*27+"+"+"-"*5+"+"+"-"*5+"+"+"-"*4+"+"+"-"*7+"+"+"-"*4+"+"+"-"*4+"+"+"-"*4+"+"+"-"*4+"+"+"-"*5+"+"+"-"*7+"+"+"-"*5)
for name, stats in loaded_players.items():
    print(" {:<25} | {:3} | {:3} | {:2} | {:2}/{:2} | {:2} | {:2} | {:2} | {:2} | {:3} | {:5} | {:3} ".format(
        name,
        sum(filter(None, map(lambda x: x.s1, stats.values()))),
        sum(filter(None, map(lambda x: x.s2, stats.values()))),
        sum(filter(None, map(lambda x: x.s3, stats.values()))),
        sum(filter(None, map(lambda x: x.s4, stats.values()))),
        sum(filter(None, map(lambda x: x.s5, stats.values()))),
        sum(filter(None, map(lambda x: x.s6, stats.values()))),
        sum(filter(None, map(lambda x: x.s7, stats.values()))),
        sum(filter(None, map(lambda x: x.s8, stats.values()))),
        sum(filter(None, map(lambda x: x.s9, stats.values()))),
        sum(filter(None, map(lambda x: x.s10, stats.values()))),
        sum(filter(None, map(lambda x: x.s11, stats.values()))),
        sum(filter(None, map(lambda x: x.s12, stats.values())))
    ))
```

`stats` is a `collections.OrderedDict` so we pass its values to a `map()` function that extracts the desired desired stat (accessed by `.` as it is a `collections.namedtuple`). This generates a list with the desired stat for every season, we then `filter()` them to remove `None` elements and `sum()` them up. This way we avoid needing to store the computed value as you were doing.

2) Get a list of the teams where a player has played over his career:

```
for name, stats in loaded_players.items():
    print("- {:25}: {}".format(
        name,
        ", ".join(set(map(lambda x: x.team, stats.values())))
    ))
```

We extract the teams with 'map()' and 'lambda' as before, transform it into a set to remove duplicates, and join them by ", " to get a comma-separated string.

3) Print the whole data:

```
print("{")
for name, all_stats in loaded_players.items():
    print("  {}: ".format(name) + "{")
    for season, stats in all_stats.items():
        print("    {}: {},".format(season, stats))
    print("  },")
print("}")
```

Comment: I've realised this code has a bug as I was not expecting two inputs for the same season. I¡t works with this 2 players but the other 2 have multiple inputs for the same season and that is not being taken into account.

Comment: Solved the bug by adding "*" to the key of the dictionary when it already exists for seasons where he played in multiple teams.

Comment: I swapped a bit the structure (sorry) to transform the `Player` `collections.namedtuple` into a `collections.OrderedDict` as it fits better. Added also how to get some value out of this container as examples.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
Unfortunately I'm not an experienced python programmer, I'm trying to test as much as I can, so I can learn from mistakes.
I will test your example and give you a feedback.